# Can the universe be considered a thermodynamic system?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, cosmology, universe

With matter a type of energy, can/should the universe be considered a thermodynamic system? At what scale would it be relevant?

Comment: Can the universe do work?

Comment: And can it do work while exchanging heat with bodies outside? If it is universe, there is no outside...

Answer (score 4):

Although it is attempting to apply thermodynamics to the whole universe, and some of the founding fathers of Thermodynamics did it, a closer inspection of the problem would suggest some caution.

Let me list the major difficulties one faces when trying to apply thermodynamics to the entire universe.

**The system**

- Do we know or control what is our system? The [observable universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe) is not the whole universe. Is it possible to say something on a system we do not fully control? And what about the interaction with the non-observable universe?
- Even if we consider the whole universe (observable and not-observable) as our system, we do not know very much about it. In particular, there is no proof that the energy of the whole universe is constant.

**What a thermodynamic system is?**

- A thermodynamic system is a system of many degrees of freedom which can be described by a bunch of variables, due to the simplifying property of thermodynamic equilibrium. Certainly, this is not the case of our present universe.
- A less demanding requirement, still allowing for a thermodynamic description, would be the hypothesis of Local Thermodynamic Equilibrium (LTE). However, we know for sure that LTE is a good approximation in many cases, but not always.

**Non-standard thermodynamics**

- Even if we limit our attention to subsets of the universe large enough that gravitational interaction plays the most important role, the properties of such systems are not standard. It is well known that gravitational systems have non-extensive thermodynamics and negative specific heat.

In a way, this last observation enables us to approximately identify the scale where gravitational interactions start to dominate as the limiting scale for usual thermodynamics.

My final conclusion is that the application of thermodynamics to the whole universe requires much more care than usually thought. Concepts like the energy or the entropy of the universe cannot simply be extrapolated from the usual meaning in a laboratory. Without an explicit theory, they are just meaningless words.

Comment: I agree, and would like, in this context, to then point out how silly it is for some scientists to "expect" a heat death of the universe based on the application of basic thermodynamic principles to a "system" that is not thermodynamically simple. More rigor is required before we tell people the universe is probably doomed (wouldn't want to start a panic)

Comment: @Jim, I  agree. However, I think that there should be a quite delicate balance between what can be safely said based on current theories and conceptual jumps or speculations based on the known Physics that can allow new progress. In this perspective, the thermal dead of the universe, introduced by the founding fathers of Thermodynamics, can be seen simultaneously as an unjustified extension of the lab-based knowledge and an interesting attempt to explore a new way to interpret data on the universe. What I think important is to maintain full control of the known limits of current theories.

Comment: @Jim A prototypic example of such an attitude was Bohr's model. Bohr knew very well that classical Physics wouldn't allow his model of the atom. Nevertheless, he decided to explore the possibility of applying in a new way part of the known Physics. At the end of the day, it is clear that it was an inconsistent attempt. However, it was a pivotal step forward in the construction of new Physics. This is the reason I only write that one has to be careful in applying Thermodynamics to the universe and I do not say it is a completely wrong idea.

Answer (score 3):

In thermodynamics theoretically anything can be defined as a system. But in so doing one must also consider what would constitute the system's surroundings and the boundary between the system and its surroundings. In that regard, if the universe were defined as a thermodynamic system, then what would constitute its surroundings? Its boundary? (especially if the universe is expanding). And with what would the system exchange mass and/or energy (work and/or heat) with?

So you see, it appears your question only raises more questions than answers. But I'm  not a cosmologist. Perhaps a cosmologist can provide a better answer.

In any event, hope this helps.

Comment: One could declare the universe as an isolated system, and concern oneself only with how different sub-systems of the universe interact with each other.

Comment: @JuanPerez Good point. And unless we can determine if there is a boundary between the universe and "everything else" (whatever that means),  then we can only deal with universe subsystems.

Answer (score 1):

It is the nature of understanding the cosmology of the observable universe that we assume as an axiom, regarding a cosmological model, that at a large scale it is homogeneous. It is impossible to know what is actually going on in that part of the universe which is not part of our observable universe. However, this fact has no relevance to whether or not a model can exist which includes the characteristic of being a thermodynamic system. However, I do remember reading somewhere (no memory of where and possibly erroneous) that there are constraints from general relativity (GR) that might possibly prevent a consistent model from combining both GR and thermodynamics.